# Corpus for Coreference Resolution Training

Tags: neural-network, nlp

I have built a neural network for coreference resolution. I need a corpus for training the neural network. Since the OntoNotes corpus has become private is there an alternative? The corpus need not be large. Any alternative with few annotated documents is fine. I just need the coreference annotation other ones are not important to me.

PS: The language in context is ENGLISH.

Comment: http://conll.cemantix.org/2011/task-description.html

Comment: @user3639557 It is the OntoNotes corpus itself. I can't download it without the LDC membership.

Answer (score 1):

I found this : http://www.cs.umd.edu/~aguha/qbcoreference which is an other english dataset based on "Removing the Training Wheels: A Coreference Dataset
that Entertains Humans and Challenges Computers" ([link here](https://people.cs.umass.edu/~miyyer/pubs/2015_naacl_qb_coref.pdf))